# Why is k10temp reporting my temperature to be exactly 255.00C?

Tags: temperature, sensors

I am running a machine using an AMD FX-8300 on a 760GM-P34 motherboard. That processor throttles at 70 C; and in the past, has only rarely (perhaps during a heavier game) gone above 30 C. I'm quite confident that this is a sensor error value, because it seems doubtful that I wouldn't be noticing if my CPU was at two and a half times the boiling point of water; additionally, it seems to be fixed right on 255.00C, with no variations.

On a user level, everything is working fine. No hiccups, no slowdowns. It's a well-taken-care-of machine with several fans and a decent amount of ventilation and internal space.

I'm not sure where to go for details on k10temp special outputs, or what this may signify and how to fix it. I'm using Linux Mint 19.1, with kernel 4.15. I usually check k10temp with the sensors panel of hardinfo.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a common bug with FX units that can cause the internal thermal sensor to output a continuous 1; for an 8-bit value, this would read as 256 or, likely, 255 C. Generally this is common on processors which do not independently support 125 W+; but I have no idea why. So, this is likely my issue; just a sensor fault.

EDIT: It seems that for some FX-* processors, the issue is triggered when one of the cores is brought to 100% load. This can cause a drain of 140 W in some instances, and 125 W seems to be a sort of protective threshold, which switches the thermal sensor output to 0xFF or 255 to trick the machine into throttling. I didn't actually notice any throttling on mine, but this does make sense; and a simple warm boot seems to have reset it. The problem seems to be relatively trivial for most of my uses.